# DynamoDB: Decrement/Subtract a key/value

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a key of type **Number** in a **DynamoDB** table. I set action as ADD to add a value to the existing value.

```
DynamoDBAttributeValue       *attr       = 
   [[[DynamoDBAttributeValue alloc] initWithN:@"1"] autorelease];
DynamoDBAttributeValueUpdate *attrUpdate = 
   [[DynamoDBAttributeValueUpdate alloc] initWithValue:attr andAction:@"ADD"];
```

Now, how do I subtract some value from the key?

Answer (score 2):

You can set `initWithN:@"-1"` to substract 1 (or any value) from the attribute when using the `ADD` action.

I think you've misused the word *key*. Keys are immutable - only attributes can be updated.